# Drawtext FPS avconv

Tags: linux, frame-rate, drawtext, avconv

Is it possible to write the fps with drawtext off avconv, i can't find information about it.

```
drawtext=fontfile=arial.ttf:text=
```

The full command i use without drawtext:

```
avconv -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -r 8 -s 640x480 -i - -an -t 00:00:30 -f rawvideo -r 8 -y \"/dev/xillybus_write_32\"
```

Comment: If the input has a frame rate of 8, you want to display 8 on the video? I doubt that is what you want but that is the impression from your question. What exactly do you want drawtext to do? I suspect ffmpeg can do what I think you want but not avconv as far as I know. They are not equivalent in terms of filtering capabilities.

Comment: Because my webcam's stream is sometimes lower 8fps, and then it outputs at for example 6 fps. And it would be usefull to show it  on my output images.